# Spring Boot on Firebase: Sign-in with redirect requires proxy

Tags: firebase, spring-boot, reverse-proxy, gateway

I have a Spring Boot application deployed on Cloud Run which also hosts an Angular web-application.

For this I am utilizing Firebase Authentication and since the web-application focuses primarily on mobile devices, I am relying on the "sign-in with redirect" (aka `signInWithRedirect()`) method provided by Firebase.

However, this means that the application is not hosted under `<project-id>.firebaseapp.com` but rather under `<somethin>.a.run.app` which is configured respectively on the web-client:

```js
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "....",
  authDomain: "<somethind>.a.run.app",
  projectId: "<project-id>",
  storageBucket: "<project-id>.appspot.com",
  // ..
}
```

This, however, seems to break the authentication flow and there's [Redirect Best Practices](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/redirect-best-practices) page in the docs which recommends to [use a proxy](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/redirect-best-practices#proxy-requests).

Essentially, any authentication request the `authDomain` has to come from the same domain. Since I am hosting the web-application myself, using Cloud Run and not Firebase Hosting, I have to deal with this myself.

There's a small example for nginx which simply adds a forwarding rule:

```nginx
# reverse proxy for signin-helpers for popup/redirect sign in.
location /__/auth {
  proxy_pass https://<project>.firebaseapp.com;
}
```

So what I did was adding a gateway rule to the respective `application.properties`:

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    # ...
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: firebase-auth
          uri: "<project-id>.firebaseapp.com"
          predicates:
            - Path: "/__/auth/**"
```

after including `spring-cloud-gateway` to my dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-gateway</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.4</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

However, testing this locally results in a simple HTTP 404 NOT_FOUND:

`http://localhost:8081/__/auth/handler?apiKey=xyz&<etc>`

What I expected was the Spring application forwarding/proxying this request to

`https://<project-id>.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler?apiKey=xyz&<etc>`

and return the response.